# Couldn’t generate collection Invalid schema supplied

Tags: postman, openapi

I'm using the Windows Postman v7.13.0 app and it's throws a cryptic message when trying to Generate a Collection from a OpenAPI spec.

Is there any way to get more detail on what the issue is? Any validator or debug option in PostMan?

```
Couldn’t generate collection

Invalid schema supplied
```

NOTE: The same `openapi: 3.0.2` spec works in Swagger UI and with the OpenAPI Generator.
I also checked the PostMan console and no logs appear to describe the issue further.

Comment: Can you post your OpenAPI file so that others can try to reproduce the issue? Have you checked your OpenAPI file for syntax errors, e.g. using https://editor.swagger.io?

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same issue and got it fixed by validating my definition as indicated on the previous comment using editor.swagger.io

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error in Postman:

> Couldn’t generate collection
>
> Could not convert the given schema

Then I tried to upload `swagger.json` to https://editor.swagger.io/ as proposed above. It showed many errors.

I opened `swagger.json` in Notepad and in the first line replaced `swagger` with `openapi`. Then saved the file and imported in Postman as usual (File > Import..., Upload Files).